# Semantic zoom grouped collection

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, semantic-zoom

IN my metro application i want to create a semantic view for the page.

For that i am manually creating a grouped collection object using foreach loop. I am not using LINQ to group the object collection because of some reason .

SO now when i try to populate semantic zoom it displays nothing(no semantic zoom).

How can i bind my own collection to grouped collection source

XAML

```
  <CollectionViewSource x:Name="GroupedSource"  IsSourceGrouped="true" />
```

Code behind file

```
  GroupedSource.Source =context.Collection; // my own grouped collection..
```

When using LINQ it working fine.But i cant use lINQ because of some reasons

Is there anything else i need to do to get

Comment: Have you read this? http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/an-introduction-to-semantic-zoom-in-windows-8-metro/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code to set the source:

```
(semanticZoom.ZoomedOutView as ListViewBase).ItemsSource = GroupedSource.View.CollectionGroups;
```

Answer (score 0):

Need a bit more detail, but.  The IsSourceGrouped="true" is only half of the story unless you bind to a hierrachal datasource. You need to specify the property that contains the child collection - ItemsPath="myItems" as an xaml property of the CollectionViewSource. If that is not the issue it may be a case of precidence of execution. put a break point and check context.Collection is populated before it is used, if context.Collection is an ObservableCollection you should be able to populate at anytime (ie. async fill).

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="GroupedSource"  IsSourceGrouped="true" ItemsPath="Items" />
```